# Rare Sign in With Apple crash

Tags: ios, swift, apple-sign-in

This is issue as been going on for months now. We can't recreate it. It is affecting multiple apps in the same way. It crashes on the same line for us as it does for other users who have reported it on the Apple forums. No suggestions yet.

```
 let appleIDProvider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()
 let request = appleIDProvider.createRequest()

 request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email] //this line crashes

 let authorizationController = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [request])
 authorizationController.delegate = self
 authorizationController.performRequests()
```

here is the full crash:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  Curio                          0x100ea895c AuthCoordinator.didTappAuthWithApple() + 138 (AuthCoordinator.swift:138)
1  Curio                          0x100d0c37c @objc AuthViewController.appleTapped() (<compiler-generated>)
2  UIKitCore                      0x1bd3a6300 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:]
3  Sentry                         0x1028f5dac (Missing)
4  UIKitCore                      0x1bce4f424 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:]
5  UIKitCore                      0x1bce4f744 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:]
6  UIKitCore                      0x1bce4e7b0 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:]
7  UIKitCore                      0x1bd3dd5c4 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:]
8  UIKitCore                      0x1bd3de7ec -[UIWindow sendEvent:]
9  UIKitCore                      0x1bd3be85c -[UIApplication sendEvent:]
10 Instabug                       0x10204c1cc (Missing)
11 UIKitCore                      0x1bd4849d4 __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue
12 UIKitCore                      0x1bd487100 __handleEventQueueInternal
13 UIKitCore                      0x1bd480330 __handleHIDEventFetcherDrain
14 CoreFoundation                 0x190b48f1c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
15 CoreFoundation                 0x190b48e9c __CFRunLoopDoSource0
16 CoreFoundation                 0x190b48784 __CFRunLoopDoSources0
17 CoreFoundation                 0x190b436c0 __CFRunLoopRun
18 CoreFoundation                 0x190b42fb4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
19 GraphicsServices               0x192d4479c GSEventRunModal
20 UIKitCore                      0x1bd3a4c38 UIApplicationMain
21 Curio                          0x100ccd3d4 main + 22 (AppDelegate.swift:22)
22 libdyld.dylib                  0x1906068e0 start
```

Comment: Crash log / error message?

Comment: just linking to the same issue on the apple dev forums incase some one adds extra info: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/132336?page=1#625049022

Comment: Have you tried to fully qualify the `.fullName` and `.email` in case there is some conflict? What other steps have you taken to investigate this?

Comment: This is the default Apple code so the only thing we have tried is to change the time in the cycle at which we run the code. The fact only a small percentage of our customers are affected by it let me to believe it’s not a qualification issue. We will try that though and feedback

Comment: @CodeBender have tried fully qualifying no luck. Thanks